# JSON Array Created in PHP/MySQL incorrectly decoded using JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am attempting to make an AJAX call to a very small PHP script that should return me an array that could be echo'd and decoded using JQuery.  Here is what I have:

My PHP page called to by AJAX:

```
$web_q=mysql_query("select * from sec_u_g where uid='$id' ");
$rs = array();
while($rs[] = mysql_fetch_assoc($web_q)) {
}
print_r(json_encode($rs));
```

This outputs:

```
[{"id":"3","uid":"39","gid":"16"},{"id":"4","uid":"39","gid":"4"},{"id":"5","uid":"39","gid":"5"},{"id":"6","uid":"39","gid":"6"},{"id":"7","uid":"39","gid":"7"},{"id":"8","uid":"39","gid":"8"},{"id":"9","uid":"39","gid":"9"},false]
```

I don't understand the "false" at the end for one ..  But then I send to to JQuery and use:

```
$.each(json.result, function(i, object) {
$.each(object, function(property, value) {
    alert(property + "=" + value);
});
});
```

This just fails.  I try to alert "result" by itself which is set by:

```
  $.post("get_ug.php",{id:txt},function(result){
  });
```

My output alerts are as follows:

```
1)  The key is '0' and the value is '['
2)  The key is '1' and the value is 'f'
3)  The key is '2' and the value is 'a'
4)  The key is '3' and the value is 'l'
5)  The key is '4' and the value is 's'
6)  The key is '5' and the value is 'e'
7)  The key is '6' and the value is ']'
8)  The key is '7' and the value is '
    '    (<-- Yes the line break is there in the alert)
```

I am exhausted from trying different ideas and scripts.  Other than setting a delimiter myself and concatenating my own array and decoding it with a custom script, does anyone have any ideas??  Thank you!!

Comment: The initial false is because the db function returns false to indicate its done, but because your code is assigning the return value directly to your array the value false gets stuck on there.  Use a temporary variable and assign it to your array inside the loop to get rid of that artifact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `false` comes from your while loop:

```
while($rs[] = mysql_fetch_assoc($web_q))
```

at the last iteration, `mysql_fetch_assoc` returns false, which is inserted to $rs[], and thus finds it way to your json.
This is also what causes your json to be invalid.
get rid of this `false` by using a temporary variable for the loop.
everything should be fine afterwards.

**Edit (Revised code with temporary variable):**

```
$web_q=mysql_query("select * from sec_u_g where uid='$id' ");
$rs = array();
$result; //temporary variable to hold the current 'fetch' result.
while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($web_q)) {
    array_push($rs, $result); //push the result into the array only if it
                              //passed the loop condition.
}
print_r(json_encode($rs));
```

**note:**
instead of `array_push($rs, $result);` you could of course also use `$rs[] = $result;`.

**Edit 2 (jQuery + json):**
in order to parse the json object, here's an example of how to build the ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "get_ug.php",
    data: {
        id: txt
    },
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json", //important (!!) - this makes sure the received data is parsed as json.
    success: function(data){
        //'data' is the resulting json object which is received from your php file.
        //use it to access your data.
        console.log( data );
    }
});
```

Comment: OK now that I understand the MySQL is generating the "false" ...  Could you clarify about the use of the temporary variable to eradicate it from the JSON array?

Comment: That worked fantastically in removing the "false" from the end.  Now My JQuery is outputting 3 alerts:  The key is '0' and the value is '['  --  The key is '0' and the value is ']' The key is '0' and the value is '' <-- with the line break  ...

Comment: Good news ...  Now I believe I have a valid JSON object notation ...  My Jquery however is iterating through every single character.   Just as I stated above, but 227 times:  The exact number of characters in the outputed JSON object. for instance  '[' '"' 'i' 'd' '"' etc ...  Is my JQuery for decoding this object valid?

Comment: OOOPS  I forgot to paseJSON ...  result = $.parseJSON(result);   ...  Thanks EyalAr  ..   You're a life saver!

Comment: @Zak, glad I could help. I just finished editing my answer again, take a look at the second edit if you like. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Why you're using print_r to print the result? It's not an recursive object anymore, so `print`  or `echo`  should be enough.